# Laravel - You don't have permission to access /images/ on this server

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel project uploaded to Heroku.

Everything works fine, except the functionality of **uploading images**.
When I attempt to upload, it shows this,

"*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /images/ on this server.*"

Here is how my store() function looks,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'filename' => 'required',
       'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
        foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path() . '/images/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Images uploaded successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the /images/ folder exists on the server and your code has write access to that folder?

Comment: @MaaikeBrouwer Thank you for replying. Yes, I'm certain images folder exist. How do I ensure there's write access to that folder?

Comment: To check the read/write access, go to your console environment of your server (I think it's possible to open a heroku environment like that?) and check the read/write permissions on the folder with ls -l   If you are not known to the outcome of this action, take a look at https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/ .  Setting the permissions should be possible with https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/353#issuecomment-31787905

Answer (score 1):

This isn't resolving your issue per-se. But you will face that other issue later on.

You shouldn't upload files directly on Heroku's filesystem if you expect them to stick around. Heroku has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Each dyno is an independent container. Whenever your app is restarted, a new container is started, meaning anything stored on the filesystem is them permanently lost.

You should upload your files to a dedicated storage system such as Google Cloud, or Amazon S3.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php